# How to secure source code in an electron desktop application

Tags: javascript, electron, v8

Since source code is viewable in a electron desktop application is there a way to obfuscate or encrypt it? We are investigating electron for a future app but worried it can be reverse engineered. How would I prevent the source code from being viewed?

Comment: Short answer: you cannot (which is true for any kind of application) - you can only make it harder to read/reverse engineer

Comment: don't think it is possible but have a look at http://enclosejs.com/ if it helps

Comment: [jsfuck.com](https://jsfuck.com)? That's certainly one way to obfuscate the JS, at least...

Comment: @jhpratt That just increases the file size, and does not help anything. It does even less then uglify. [WANNA DECODE JSFUCK?](https://enkhee-osiris.github.io/Decoder-JSFuck/)

Comment: @t.niese I didn't say it would help. OP asked for ways to obfuscate or encrypt. It certainly obfuscates it.

Comment: A Good question with a simple answer: you can't!

Comment: @jhpratt With jsfuck your are able to get the original source back. If  jsfuck counts as obfuscation, then you could also say, zip the source file, because it has the same level of _"obfusaction"_ but the benefit that the file size would be decreased.